# how do you use cygwin to compile an R package from source?

Tags: r, cygwin

I am trying to install an R package from source:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdq-qnm-pkg/files/PDQ-R%20Source/6.1-1/pdq_6.1-1.tar.gz

I cannot install RTools to compile but I have Cygwin. How can install this package from source using Cygwin?

when I do this:

```
install.packages("pdq_6.1-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

I get this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘PDQ-6.2.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Highly unlikely. The balance of tools to compile R and R packages for windows is hard-fought and carefully maintained. Linking DLLs that are compiled with other tool-chains is effectively untenable. (You might infer that it'd be feasible to re-compile all of R and then work on the package(s) from there ... that may take more effort than it's worth.)

Comment: @user1471980 Why can't you install RTools? You can always install without Admin privileges (any folder where you have sufficient writing privileges will do) and then use a bat file which adds the file path to your %PATH% before starting RStudio. This might be a workaround in your case. Let me know if you need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the failures, you can not solve the issue.
I assume you are missing some tools or libraries.
See http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html
and try

```
R CMD INSTALL pdq_6.1-1.tar.gz
```

On my cygwin system with R-3.2.4

```
$ R CMD INSTALL pdq_6.1-1.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘pdq’ ...
** libs
gcc -I/usr/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -D__R_PDQ       -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -std=gnu99 -fdebug-prefix-map=/cygdrive/e/cyg_pub/devel/R/R-3.2.4-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/R-3.2.4-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/cygdrive/e/cyg_pub/devel/R/R-3.2.4-1.x86_64/src/R-revised=/usr/src/debug/R-3.2.4-1  -c MVA_Approx.c -o MVA_Approx.o
[cut]
gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -o pdq.dll MVA_Approx.o MVA_Canon.o MVA_Solve.o PDQ_Build.o PDQ_Exact.o PDQ_Globals.o PDQ_MServer.o PDQ_Report.o PDQ_Utils.o pdq.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -ltirpc -lrt -ldl -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
installing to /usr/lib/R/site-library/pdq/libs
** R
** demo
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘print’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘pdq’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (pdq)
```