# Build R package in Windows under Cygwin

Tags: r, cygwin

When trying to update R package dplyr to 0.7.0 from source on Win10 under Cygwin (windows binary for dplyr 0.7.0 is not available. Also my R installation in not under Cygwin and my R installation is from binary). However when I run

```
R CMD INSTALL dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz
```

see the following error:

```
* installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library'
* installing *source* package 'dplyr' ...
** package 'dplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG    -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -DRCPP_USING_UTF8_ERROR_STRING -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/BH/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/bindrcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/plogr/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c   RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/bin/sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: RcppExports.o]    Error 127
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R -34~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="dplyr.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o address.o api.o arrange.o between.o bind.o combine_variables.o distinct.o filter.o group_by.o group_indices.o hybrid.o hybrid_count.o hybrid_debug.o hybrid_in.o hybrid_minmax.o hybrid_nth.o hybrid_offset.o hybrid_simple.o hybrid_window.o init.o init_register.o join.o join_exports.o mutate.o rlang-export.o select.o set.o slice.o summarise.o test.o utils.o window.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'dplyr'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/dplyr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/dplyr'
```

The cause of error is R (using Rtools library) looks for g++/gcc compilers under c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/ and not under Cygwin /usr/bin/

Is there a way to change this default behavior of R CMD INSTALL which would allow building R packages from source in Windows without Rtoools?

Thanks

PS. I think this post
[how do you use cygwin to compile an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416543/how-do-you-use-cygwin-to-compile-an-r-package-from-source/44474950#44474950)
is relevant, but it appears R was installed under Cygwin, which is not my case.

PPS. It appears I need to change variables defined under

```
R CMD config
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: you can not use cygwin compiler for building a windows only binary

Comment: That's what I figured. Reading Windows related R documentation, there are enough boxes to check as is (including compilation details specific to each package) that adding Cygwin to that mix is just not worth the time right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the *best* solution is. But you can certainly fix this by modifying BINPREF in `$(R_HOME)/etc/x64/Makeconf`. `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/` is the default value.

PS: You almost certainly *can* use the cygwin compiler to build R packages, as long as only C linkage is involved. I build some of mine under Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks @DaBookshah, that's the file to setup/modify environment variables in order to compile R libraries from source under Windows. Assuming limited compilation of packages that involve only C linkages, there's at least two things to explore further: 1. is gcc version important (R is compiled with v4.9.3, my Cygwin installation is 5.4.0) and 2. is Rtools still required?

Comment: 1. gcc version is *highly unlikely* to be important. As far as I'm aware, all function calls between R and R packages use C linkage, which should be fine.


2. Rtools probably isn't required, provided you have all the standard stuff accessible, e.g. make, cp, cat, basename, etc. I've never personally tested that kind of configuration though.

Comment: thanks for your feedback again. After updating Makeconf, I tried to update three R packages (DBI, DBItest and bindrcpp) from source since Windows binaries are not available. First two complied, installed and tested successfully. However, during installation of bindrcpp, the installer hangs when loading the installed package. I see the updated files in $(R_HOME)/library/bindrcpp folder, with an additional folder 00LOCK-bindrcpp, which I assume is where the installer is working/testing the installation. Interestingly, I see two R process running in Windows task manager (contd.)

Comment: (contd.)... although, I killed the R install process in Cygwin, with one of those processes is still using CPU. When I force kill those two processes in Windows Task Manager, both folders $(R_HOME)/library/bindrcpp and 00LOCK-bindrcpp are deleted!, leaving me to install bindrcpp using the latest available binary.

Comment: I noticed that Makeconf file directs the compiler/linker to `-I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"`, `-Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib` and `-Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64`. How do these libraries come into play when building R packages from source? Thx

Comment: Update re compilation to update packages - it turns out DBI and DBItest didn't need compilation to update. However when I tried to update another package RSQLite from source, the installer gets through the compilation and installation as before, but when testing loading the new package, it exits this time with status 1. So the bottom line is that packages which require compilation cannot be upgraded with my setup. Any thoughts on what the issue could be? Thank You.

Comment: Both RSQLite and Bindrcpp have LinkingTo: Rcpp. That's a C++ linkage, and you can't do that kind of linkage across different compilers - In this case across major versions of gcc. If you want to compile those packages from source using your cygwin gcc, you need to also compile Rcpp from source using the same compiler. That's my guess at what's wrong, anyway.