# Ryacas build failing in Windows

Tags: r, windows, build

I just upgraded R and R Tools from 3.3 to 3.5 and then set my installation packages to my 3.3 folder.  I am trying get a bioClite package that seems to need an updated installation of "Ryacas" package.  Apparently when I use install.packages("Ryacas") with or without depen = TRUE it says it can only be compile as C++ so I let R Tools build it and I get this error every time.

Here is the error:

```
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: 
yacas/src/obmalloc.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Ryacas'
* removing 'C:/Users/bjwil/OneDrive/Documents/R/R/win-library/3.3/Ryacas'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘Ryacas’ had non-zero exit status`
```

And here is the session info.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United 
States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   
base     

other attached packages:
[1] Biobase_2.40.0      BiocGenerics_0.26.0 arules_1.6-1        Matrix_1.2- 
14      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1  tools_3.5.1     rpart_4.1-13    grid_3.5.1      
lattice_0.20-35
```

Here is my `.libPaths()`

```
[1] "C:/Users/******/OneDrive/Documents/R/R/win-library/3.3"
[2] "C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Client/R_SERVER/library" 
[3] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library"
```

I see this person has a log file of this issue happening last month.  Is R Tools broken, is it R?  Happens in both R Desktop and R Studio.
http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/check/Ryacas-check.log

Comment: What happens when you carefully follow the directions on: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/ryacas

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that if adding BINPREF variable in the .Renviron to change the make: as indicated in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475752/build-r-package-in-windows-under-cygwin does not work.  I tried it again and the build is way past where it was failing before.  Ill post the github repo url regarding the issue if it works.

Comment: Nope after I tried the github build i get this error.  It just a plain issue with new R Tools.  I feel like everyone is having issues with it. `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Ryacas'
* removing 'C:/Users/*****/OneDrive/Documents/R/R/win-library/3.3/Ryacas'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)`